# Positive term for "curious"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, connotation

I'm looking for a synonym for "curious" that is undoubtedly positive. "Curious" itself is fairly neutral--it *could* be interpreted as a good thing, but it's sometimes seen as a bad thing (i.e., "Curiosity killed the cat."). There are plenty of other synonyms that are wholly negative: "nosy," "snoopy," "prying," etc. Are there any other synonyms for "curious" that make it clear it's a good thing, such as to describe someone who's curious about an academic subject and wants to learn more about it?

I've already tried Webster.com's [thesaurus search](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/curious), as well as [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/curious) and [synonym.com](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/curious/), but the only results there are either neutral or negative.

Comment: What about *interesting*?

Comment: Or are you using it, not as "Now that's curious", but rather as "She is very curious about everything"?  In which case, "She's very interested in everything." seems to work well.

Comment: 'Fascinated by' rarely introduces harmful referents.

Comment: I would use it in the sense of "She's very curious about X."

Comment: 'inquisitive'? Although I think 'interested' or 'fascinated by', as already suggested, are better.

Comment: 'Insatiable appetite for knowledge' ?

Comment: "Inquisitive" is the first word I thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if used in the context you've described curious will consistently have a positive connotation; I can't conceive of how curiosity about an academic subject could be taken negatively.

Perhaps the word 'interested' is less likely to be construed negatively. "She was interested in biology".

I think that any negative connotation attached to any word that describes inquisitiveness stems from the human desire for privacy; there will always be certain subjects that people don't want examined, as such there will always be the potential for any type of inquisitiveness to be spun negatively.